# Angular KendoGrid is not visible

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to use KendGrid component in my angular project.

I have followed an example to create a Grid, and I'm able to fetch the data and assign to a variable 'gridData' in component.ts (I can see the data via console).

In my html, I'm using following script

```html
<p>
    Kendo UI Datagrid example
  </p>
  <kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="gridData" [height]="370" style="color: red;">
      <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="40">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="250">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="Category.CategoryName" title="Category">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Price" width="80">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="UnitsInStock" title="In stock" width="80">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" title="Discontinued" width="120">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
              <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.Discontinued" disabled/>
          </ng-template>
      </kendo-grid-column>
  </kendo-grid>
```

When I do 'npm run' only `<p>` tag is shown on the UI but KendoGrid is not visible and console has no errors.

I have `import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';` in my component module and also in my main app module.

Can you help me with what is missing with my KendoGrid.